# Android Jetpack Navigation Exception "Navigation can not be found from the current destination"

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm facing some Android Jetpack Navigation Exceptions when navigating from one fragment to another with an action. I know what problem leads to such kind of exceptions. These do not occur in normal use. But there where some traced exceptions in Crashlytics. So it seems to be sometimes a problem. Maybe with the lifecycle or something.

My general question: Is there a way or best practice to check or deal with such kind of navigation exception?

It can't be a good solution to put every navigation statement in a try - catch block.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this extension to ignore when you're trying to move to a destination that you shouldn't be able to access:

```
fun NavController.navigateSafely(srcId: Int, actionId: Int, bundle: Bundle) {
    if (currentDestination?.id == srcId) {
        navigate(actionId, bundle)
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems to be a great idea. Just one question: How do I get the srcId? currentDestination.id?

Comment: currentDestination comes from NavController, but srcId would be the "expected source from which you navigate".

Comment: Ah sorry, now I got the trick. Many THX!

Comment: I guess I'm doing something wrong. Most of the time a got a srcId = 0. Can you pls give me an example how to call your function?